# COMSOL coil group which crosses the modeling plane more than once

Tags: simulation, comsol

I'm trying to model a system in the magnetic field, 2D-axisymmetric environment, with current loops which pass the modeling place both once and more than once.

I've read [here](https://doc.comsol.com/5.5/doc/com.comsol.help.acdc/acdc_ug_modeling.06.18.html) that the solution should be to mark the coils which pass through the plane more than once as a group, but for me it doesn't seem to work. From what I see, it appears that the coils which cross the plane twice (on the right-hand side) are not modelled properly.

All coils are a homogenised multi-group, if that matters.

I'm attaching a 3D model of my setup (with the brown representing the coils, grey the iron core, and the ), and also COMSOL's steady-state results.

I've tried playing around with other parameters such as increasing current and number of coil turns, but didn't see much effect.

[image]

[image]

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played around a bit more, and have figured out a workaround, even though I'm sure there's a more "elegant" solution out there.

Considering that the coil on the right hand side has current entering from one of the cross-sections, and exiting from the other one, one can just treat the coils as individual coils, each with +I and -I current flowing through them.

That is, don't use the "coil group" selection, but rather treat each cross-section of the coil as an individual coil. Just make sure to keep an eye on the polarity of this solenoid i.e. which cross-section has positive current flowing through it and which has negative.

The image below shows the desired result.

[image]